# Why is Integrate[Exp[-x^2/s^2],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}] not the same as -Integrate[Exp[-x^2/s^2],{x,Infinity,-Infinity}]]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

Version 12.1

```
Clear[s]

Integrate[Exp[-x^2/s^2],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

generates the correct conditions. But,

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2/s^2],{x,Infinity,-Infinity}]]
```

doesn't.  This isn't strictly incorrect--but strange?

Comment: You're missing the right bracket for the Exp in both code blocks and the title.

Comment: They are if you assume `Re[s^2] > 0` or any tighter restriction such as `Element[s, Reals]` or `s > 0`

Comment: That’s corrrct. My question is why don’t both expressions generate conditions (the same conditions)

Comment: Thanks @flinty. Edited.

Comment: Probably a buglet somewhere.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks Danny (and nice to hear from you).  Is it worth filing as a buglet.

Comment: Craig, Yes, worth filing. I actually get unevaluated when I try the second example. Not really better, not really worse*, and about just as weird. (*) Actually that is really worse. We should be able to integrate a Gaussian, even with a symbolic parameter. So maybe bigger than a buglet. I guess I need to take a look.

Comment: Seems fixed in MMA 12.2. I got `ConditionalExpression[-(Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Sqrt[(1/s^2)]), Re[s^2] > 0]` for the second example.

Answer (score 1):

In 12.1.0 on Windows 10 `Integrate[Exp[-x^2/s^2], {x, Infinity, -Infinity}]` returns unevaluated. This can be done through

```
Limit[Integrate[Exp[-x^2/s^2],{x,a,b}],{a,b}->{Infinity,-Infinity}]
(*ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[\[Pi]] s, s > 0]*)
```

Up to usual conventions, the sign of a definite integral changes to the opposite one if we replace the limits of the integration.